# ssl certificate on localhost subdomain not working

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, xampp, virtualhost

I have a problem with my subdomain not working for SSL on localhost.

I generated my SSL certificate as "localhost" for my XAMPP installation.

I normally have TWO document roots:

```
DocumentRoot C:\Files\PHPCode
ServerName phpcode.localhost
```

&

```
DocumentRoot C:\server\xampp
ServerName localhost
```

I can get Chrome to work in SSL if I use https://localhost, but it wont work for the subdomain virtualhost https://phpcode.localhost

Did I make mistake in generating the SSL for localhost only ? Or can I change some setting to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work edited the v3.ext file and put the altnames to have both hosts:

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
DNS.2 = phpcode.localhost
```

Then used:

```
bin\openssl x509 -in server.csr -out server.crt -req -signkey server.key -days 365 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext
```

and everythings good Chrome and Edge work fine.

Comment: where do you get the v3.ext file?

Answer (score 0):

A certificate must match the name in the URL. A certificate issued for `localhost` only will not match a URL using `phpcode.localhost` as domain name. No setting on client or server can bypass this requirement. You need to either use a different certificate for this domain or create a certificate which includes both names.